# Question on designing a REST API to return possible nested resources

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I have a Controller for a resource called Checklist. A Checklist can have multiple UserRights. A UserRight contains the ChecklistGuid, UserGuid and an AccessModifier (Read/Write).

I have following routes to work with UserRights:

`GET /api/Checklist/{ChecklistGuid}/UserRight`

`PUT /api/Checklist/{ChecklistGuid}/UserRight`

`DELETE /api/Checklist/{ChecklistGuid}/UserRight`

My question is: How would a route returning all Users who are not already assigned to a specific checklist look like?

I added another route ".../UserRight/UsersNotAssigned" but i dont like this way.

Comment: Besides the actual question being opinionated, which is not in scope with SO's agenda, REST doesn't care how you "design" your URI. In fact, designing overengineered URIs may just leed to [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) meaningful to clients which REST should not have at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think /api/unassignedUsers will be fit since usually by looking at the resource path, we have to understand the result that we are getting.